# Detect DELETE (backspace) in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, key-events

Is there any way to to detect that DEL(backspace) is pressed in Android Soft Keyboard? KeyListener() is not working for me. Please give me another solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Numeric key register backspace pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101407/android-numeric-key-register-backspace-pressed)

Comment: Could you let us know what exactly doesn't work and what you've tried?

Comment: @Wirling yes i am trying to auto correct the word as user is typing and if user doesn't like my suggestion and presses backspace to remove the word then i want to display list of suggestion. so i need to detect backspace to display suggestions.

Comment: @AsadMahmood this post would probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Comment: @Wirling this is not working and i have mentioned in my question that KeyListener is not working for me.

Comment: @Wirling onKeyListener doesn't work for soft keyboards

Comment: @AsadMahmood can you post some code so we can figure out why it isn't working for you?